# More choices in FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo

How to change "more choices" label in the filteringselect.Kindly help me resolve the issue.Below is the code i tried,which is the normal code used in FilteringSelect Example i executed this in notepad++.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src='dojo/dojo.js'></script>
    <script>
require([
    "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory, FilteringSelect){
    var stateStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
            {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
            {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
            {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
            {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
            {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
            {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
            {name:"Alifornia", id:"AA"},
            {name:"Aolorado", id:"AO"},
            {name:"Aonnecticut", id:"AT"},
            {name:"Aelaware", id:"AE"},
            {name:"Blabama", id:"BL"},
            {name:"Blaska", id:"BK"},
            {name:"Bmerican Samoa", id:"BS"},
            {name:"Brizona", id:"BZ"},
            {name:"Brkansas", id:"BR"},
            {name:"Brmed Forces Europe", id:"BE"},
            {name:"Brmed Forces Pacific", id:"BP"},
            {name:"Brmed Forces the Americas", id:"BA"},
            {name:"Balifornia", id:"BA"},
            {name:"Bolorado", id:"BO"},
            {name:"Bonnecticut", id:"BT"},
            {name:"Belaware", id:"BE"},
            {name:"Dlabama", id:"DL"},
            {name:"Dlaska", id:"DK"},
            {name:"Dmerican Samoa", id:"DS"},
            {name:"Drizona", id:"DZ"},
            {name:"Drkansas", id:"DR"},
            {name:"Drmed Forces Europe", id:"DE"},
            {name:"Drmed Forces Pacific", id:"DP"},
            {name:"Drmed Forces the Americas", id:"DA"},
            {name:"Dalifornia", id:"DA"},
            {name:"Dolorado", id:"DO"},
            {name:"Dnecticut", id:"DT"},
            {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
        ]
    });

    var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
        id: "stateSelect",
        name: "state",
        value: "CA",
        store: stateStore,
        forceWidth:true,
        pageSize:10,
        searchAttr: "name"
    }, "stateSelect");
});
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .dijitInputField
    {
        font-size:13;
    }
    .dijitPlaceHolder
    {
        font-size:13;
    }
    .dijitMenuItem
    {
        font-size:0.8em;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <input id="stateSelect">
<p>
    <button onclick="alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('value'))">Get value</button>
    <button onclick="alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('displayedValue'))">Get displayed value</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "More choices" will appear at the end of drop down

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but it's not easy. Dojo defined the "More choices" message in their localized messages, which you can see [here](https://raw.github.com/dojo/dijit/master/form/nls/ComboBox.js).

You cannnot change them directly, but you can override the method where it's used. That's the tricky part, after reading the code I noticed that dropdowns are loaded by using the `dropDownClass` property which is by default `_ComboBoxMenu`. This class is where the message is actually used (actually it's a mixin), so we need to subclass this class and extend its behaviour, for example:

```js
var CustomizedMenu = declare([_ComboBoxMenu], {
    buildRendering: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.nextButton.innerHTML = "More states"; // New text
    }
});
```

As you can see here, we change the html content of the `nextButton` to something else in the `buildRendering` method. It's here where it's originally placed, so we replace it afterwards, that's why we use `this.inherited(arguments);` first because that means that the superclass function is first executed.

Afterwards we just change the `dropDownClass` of the select, like this:

```js
var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
    id: "stateSelect",
    name: "state",
    value: "CA",
    dropDownClass: CustomizedMenu, // Just change it
    store: stateStore,
    forceWidth:true,
    pageSize:10,
    searchAttr: "name"
}, "stateSelect");
```

You can see the complete code example on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/94mCG/).